# How do I reference a local instance of Jquery in a Webview

Tags: c#, jquery, webview, windows-store-apps

I have a C# Windows Store App with a `WebView` which loads some local HTML. I do this via the `NavigateToString` method. I want to include jQuery but so far the only way I can get this to work is either using the ajax hosted libraries or pasting the entire library into a script tag on the same page.

I've tried putting it in the `Assets` folder, ensuring that its set to Content / Copy If Newer, and I've tried the following paths to it with no success

```
Assets/jquery-2.1.0.min.js

/Assets/jquery-2.1.0.min.js

./Assets/jquery-2.1.0.min.js

~/Assets/jquery-2.1.0.min.js

ms-appx:///Assets/jquery-2.1.0.min.js
```

I've tried putting it in a /js subfolder in the app, as I've seen this done in some examples online. I've also tried adding JQuery through NuGet. Neither of these steps really made sense to me and they obviously didn't work, but I thought they were worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, I got the inspiration to try one more thing while finishing up my StackOverflow question. This works:

```
ms-appx-web:///Assets/jquery-2.1.0.min.js
```

This URI Scheme `ms-appx-web` is mentioned [in this msdn post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx), but it doesn't explicitly state in which cases it should be used over `ms-appx:`. I guess accessing local resources from a `WebView` is one of those cases.